# AngularJS : How to test a promise resolved in a callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise

I have written a function which opens an indexedDB. I'm using a promise, because I think it is the cleanest way to handle this.

```
  this.$get = function($q, $rootScope, $window) {
    return {
      finalize: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var dbRequest = $window.indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);
        dbRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
          // XXX do something here.
        };
        dbRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
          db = event.target.result;
          console.log('Success!');
          deferred.resolve(event);
        };
        dbRequest.onerror = deferred.reject;
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  };
```

In order to test this, I have created the following test function:

```
  describe('finalize', function() {
    it('should initialize the database', function(done) {
      var promise = resource.finalize();
      promise.then(function() {
        console.log('resolved');
        var transaction = resource.db.transaction(['Component']);
        expect(transaction).toBeDefined();
        done();
      });
      $rootScope.$apply();
    });
  });
```

This prints `'Success!'` in the console, but the promise is never resolved.

If I move `$rootScope.$apply()` to the end of the onsuccess function, the promise is resolved, but only for one test. Other tests then throw an error `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`.

How should I resolve this promise? Is a callback function better?

Answer (score 2):

```
this.$get = function($q, $rootScope, $window) {
    return {
      finalize: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var dbRequest = $window.indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);
        dbRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
          // XXX do something here.
        };
        dbRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
          db = event.target.result;
          console.log('Success!');
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
             deferred.resolve(event);
           });              
        };
        dbRequest.onerror = function (error) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                deferred.reject(error);
             });
         } 
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  };
```

Also you should use var promise = resource.finalize(); one time for all tests

Comment: I have tried this solution, but it still fails with the error message I provided. I noticed it fails when combining with `$httpBackend.flush();`